# angular-ui-popover arrow positioning is wrong in auto positioning mode

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

The popover's arrow is messed up after a couple of repositioning.

See this screencast:
[image: Screencast of the issue]

Plunker link:
https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/hBjJhoNQSZ40xNsY

I know the library is not maintained actively. Is there a workaround for this issue? In my case, it is even okay if the 'auto' positioning is done only when the popover opens. Is it possible to avoid repositioning during digest cycles?